# Add datetime format to cell array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, datetime, cell

I have a cell array that I call "Table", as in the code below (but my array has more lines). Column 1 contains dates in string format. I want to add an additional column that contains the dates in datetime format. I did the following, which works, but it is VERY slow. What are the alternatives?

```
% Table that I have:

Table{1,1} = 'Stringdate';
Table{2,1} = '01.01.1999';
Table{3,1} = '02.01.1999';
Table{4,1} = '03.01.1999';
Table{5,1} = '04.01.1999';

% What I want to add:

Table{1, size(Table,2)+1} = 'Datetime';

for index = 2:length(Table)
    Table{index, size(Table,2)} = datetime(Table{index, 1});
end
```

Comment: The code runs perfectly on my machine?! Feel free to change it if it doesn't work for you and thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply [`datetime`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html) to all of them in one-go and use just [`num2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html) and indexing to achieve the same result as that of your loop.

```
Table(2:end,2) = num2cell(datetime(Table(2:end,1)));
%You might need to specify the InputFormat as well i.e.
%Table(2:end,2) = num2cell(datetime(Table(2:end,1),'InputFormat','dd.MM.yyyy'));
```